# Optimize performance for dense ranking algo

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance

I'm doing this [challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/climbing-the-leaderboard/problem?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen) to assign [dense rankings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranking#:%7E:text=as%20a%20gap.-,Dense%20ranking%20(%221223%22%20ranking),respect%20to%20the%20ranking%20order.) to a player's score compared to a leadingboard. My following code works, but takes too long to run (some tests on the site fail on timeout error).

I'm wondering what else can I optimize? Any ideas?

```js
function climbingLeaderboard(scores, alice) {
  const reducedScores = getReducedScores(scores)
  let lastIdxHit = reducedScores.length - 1
  return alice.map((a) => {
    for (let i = lastIdxHit; i >= 0; i--) {
      const rs = reducedScores[i]
      if (a < rs.value) {
        return rs.rank + 1
      }
      lastIdxHit = i - 1
    }
    return 1
  })
}

function getReducedScores(scores) {
  let rank = 0
  return scores.reduce((acc, s) => {
    if (last(acc) && last(acc).value === s) {
      return acc
    }
    rank++
    return acc.concat({ value: s, rank })
  }, [])
}

function last(arr) {
  return arr[arr.length - 1]
}
```

Comment: Do you search rank for every alice[i] value from the beginning (`let rank = 0`)?

Comment: no, I only assign ranks once on `getReducedScores`. I posted the entire code, you can see it there

Comment: I am not strong in JS specific features like map and reduce. But  does `rs = reducedScores.find` perform new search for every `alice[i] `?

Comment: yes, I don't see another way of doing it since I need to find the respected item for each alice[i]

Comment: I made Python code, hope it is understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code performs full search of every `alice[]` value in `scores` to determine it's rank, so time complexity is quadratic `O(n*m)`.

But both arrays are sorted `scores is in descending order. alice are in ascending order.`

We can exploit this fact to make **linear** search.

In this Python code the first part finds rank at the array end.

Then for every `alice` element we look for appropriate place, correcting `rank` when `scores` changes.

```
scores = [100, 100, 50, 40, 40, 20, 10]
alice = [5, 25, 50, 120]

#scores = [100, 90, 90, 80, 75, 60]
#alice = [50, 65, 77, 90, 102]

n = len(scores)
m = len(alice)
rank = 1
for i in range(1, len(scores)):
    if scores[i] < scores[i-1]:
        rank +=1

j = len(scores) - 1
for a in alice:
    while j >= 0 and a >= scores[j]:
        j -=1
        if (j < 0) or (scores[j] > scores[j+1]):
            rank -=1
    print(rank+1)

output
  6 4 2 1
  #6 5 4 2 1
```

Both `score` index `j` and `alice` index `i` move in one direction only (forward and backward), so complexity is linear `O(m+n)`

Comment: No, site requires authorization

Answer (score 0):

Some of the key points to keep in mind to optimize your data structure and algorithms using javascript, is to:

1. Avoid using prototype functions as much as possible when using javascripts.
2. Find alternatives to making unnecessary large storage.
3. Skip some repeating steps by breaking through loops when they are no longer needed.

Keeping the above in mind, here is what my solution would look like.

```js
    function climbingLeaderboard(scores: number[], alice: number[]): number[] {
        var rankings : number[] = [];
        var positions: number = 0;
        
        for (var index = 0; index < scores.length; index++) {
            if (index === 0 || scores[index] < scores[index - 1]) {
                positions++;
            }
        }
        
        let startingIndex = scores.length - 1;
        for(var jndex = 0; jndex < alice.length; jndex++) {
            for(var index = startingIndex; index >= 0; index--) {
                if (scores[index] >= scores[index - 1]) {
                    continue;
                }
                
                if (alice[jndex] < scores[index]) {
                    startingIndex = index;
                    break;
                }
                
                if (alice[jndex] >= scores[index]) {
                    positions--;
                }
            }
            rankings[rankings.length] = positions + 1;
        }
        return rankings;
    }
```