# Python ranking without skipping number (dense rank)

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, ranking

Using python 3.x I would like to achieve dense rank(do not skip number if the ranks are repeated ). I have the below array sorted according to score

```
rank_list = [{'Id': 236966, 'score': 91.0}, {'Id': 237241, 'score': 82.0}, {'Id': 237077, 'score': 79.0}, {'Id': 237084, 'score': 78.0}, {'Id': 237080, 'score': 72.0}, {'Id': 237236, 'score': 71.0}, {'Id': 236979, 'score': 71.0}, {'Id': 236909, 'score': 67.0}, {'Id': 237174, 'score': 67.0}, {'Id': 237035, 'score': 66.0}]
```

I used the below code to calculate and assign the 'rank' field but the code skips a rank if there is a rank repeated

```
def rankFunc(e):
    return e['score']

rank_list.sort(key = rankFunc, reverse=True)
sorted_scores = [obj['score'] for obj in rank_list]
ranks = [sorted_scores.index(x) for x in sorted_scores]
for index, obj in enumerate(rank_list):
    obj['rank'] = ranks[index]+1
```

the current output:

rank = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 8, 8, 10]

I would like ranks to be assigned without skipping any number like below,

rank = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8]

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63278636

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This little helper function should solve your problem:

```
def rank_unique(x, **kwargs):
    sx = sorted(set(x), **kwargs)
    invsx = {s: i for i, s in enumerate(sx)}
    return [1 + invsx[v] for v in x]

>>> rank_unique([r["score"] for r in rank_list], reverse=True)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 2):

This simple solution will solve your problem (assuming the array is already sorted).

> ```
> def assignRank(_list):
>     rank = 0
>     for i in range(len(_list)):
>         if _list[i]["score"] != _list[i-1]["score"]:
>             rank += 1
>         _list[i]["rank"] = rank
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dense rank method with pandas function

```
import pandas as pd
rank = pd.Series(sorted_scores).rank(method="dense",ascending=False).values
print(rank)
```

output:

```
[1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 6. 7. 7. 8.]
```